# How to use enum array parameter on switch case statement?

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I had the following method:

```
private int EarthAttributeValue()
{
   var totalValue = 0;

   foreach (var item in ItemList)
   {
       switch (item.Attribute)
       {
          case AttributeEnum.Earth:
             totalValue += item.AttributeValue;
          break;
       }
    }
   
   return totalValue;
}
```

But i didnt want to create a new method for every value in my Enum, so i'm trying to create a generic method for any attribute, receiving the "target enum" as a parameter.

I've tried this one

```
private int AttributeValue(AttributeEnum attribute)
{
   var totalValue = 0;

   foreach (var item in ItemList)
   {
       switch (item.Attribute)
       {
          case attribute:
             totalValue += item.AttributeValue;
          break;
       }
   }
   
   return totalValue;
}
```

But it doesn't build, saying that i need a constant value for the case (since the parameter is a variable).

Is there any way to do this? Using Reflection perhaps?

**Obs.: I don't want to use an if instead of the switch because the item.Attribute gonna be a list soon, so as the parameter.**

Comment: You could simplify all to this: `int earthTotal = ItemList.Where(item => item.Attribute == AttributeEnum.Earth).Sum(item => item.AttributeValue)`

Comment: I can't really tell exactly what you are trying to do (more code wode help), but I'm guessing that using LINQ (like @TimSchmelter suggests) but 
adding in `GroupBy` is probably a path to what you are looking for

Comment: a [mre] would be nice =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created this one, replacing the *switch* by a Linq *lambda*:

```
internal int AttributeValue(AttributeEnum attribute)
{
   return ItemList
     .Where(x => x.Attribute == attribute)
     .Sum(x => x.AttributeValue);
}
```

Thanks @TimSchmelter for the help!